# Rabbitmq and catch all queue

Tags: queue, rabbitmq, catch-all

In my company I'm running a battery of tests running on different android devices.

Today tests (that are tasks) are running  in a single queue with multiple workers.

I want to split this single queue in multiple queue, one for every device in order to optimize tests launches according to how many X devices my company has (i.e. if my company has 2 A devices I want to send tests on devices A in a queue with a single worker with --concurrency=2 so that I can launch max two test in a row).

I don't want migrate all in a time so I'm taking a first step to implement an hybrid version and logic I'd like to implement is the following.

Device **A** (there are two of them) and **B** (it's only one) go on queue **A** and queue **B** while all the others in the old **legacy** one.

[image]

My problem is with **legacy** queue. If I send a test on a device C, what I do is sending the task to queue **C**, since the catch_all queue is named **legacy** the task is not received.
I'm searching a way to say: 
"please Rabbitmq use queue **legacy** if an existing queue name does not match with the device name".

There is a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this with a combination of Alternate Exchange (https://www.rabbitmq.com/ae.html), and bindings with routing keys

Your setup would have QueueA and QueueB bound through your exchange, using a binding key that represents the device.

```
| exchange| binding  | queue  |
|---------|----------|--------|
|  my.ex  | device.a | QueueA |
|  my.ex  | device.b | QueueB |
```

when you publish a message from Device A, it would have a routing key of `device.a` and would go to QueueA.

Now for all of the legacy devices, you would set up an alternate exchange on the exchange configuration. This would deliver messages that don't match `device.a` or `device.b` routing keys, to the alternate exchange.

The alternate exchange would then route all messages to the legacy queue.